# Mocking GetX controller lifecycle

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I have a controller in GetX where onInit() has some initilaztion of services. In my testing, I don't need to test the onInit() method. But because onInit() is invoked automatically, I'm having trouble testing the controller. Is it possible to mock the onInit() method using Mockito or Mocktail?

Currently I'm trying the following, but seems it doesn't work

```dart
class MyControllerMock extends Mock implements MyController {
  @override
  void onInit() async {}
```

While invoking `super.onInit()` on the onInit() function I'm getting the following error

`The method 'onInit' is always abstract in the supertype.`

Comment: Try adding "return null;" in that oiInit() override method.